# How to corectly query for type "dict"?

Tags: python, list, sqlite, type-conversion

For my quiz application I have a module which asks questions, shows the 4 possible answers in a listbox, then you click a button to fetch result and check if true.

Data type is interpreted incorrectly as a list, I convert to type:dict but then the code does not interpret it the same as if manually defined. How can I restructure either query or conversion function so dict type is correct? Current interpretation jumbles the order and removes some elements :

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import sqlite3
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

SentenceFrame = Toplevel()

#Connect to a Database
conn=sqlite3.connect('Question_Bank.db')
c = conn.cursor()

records=[]

#Query into Table
records = c.execute("SELECT Question, Correct_Answer, Option1 ,Option2 ,Option3  FROM Question_Bank").fetchall()

#commit changes
conn.commit()

#close connection
conn.close()

How_it_works = {
"First US State?": [
    "Delaware",
    "Ohio", 
    "Texas", 
    "Maryland"
],
"Fastest car?": [
    "Ferrari", 
    "Mercedes", 
    "BMW", 
    "Tesla"
],
}

print(How_it_works)
print(type(How_it_works))
print((len(How_it_works)))

def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct

print(records)
print(len(records))
print(type(records))

QUESTIONS=Convert(records)

print(QUESTIONS)
print(type(QUESTIONS))
print((len(QUESTIONS)))

my_listbox=Listbox(SentenceFrame)
my_listbox.grid(row=6, column=1)

QuestionLabel = Label(SentenceFrame, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20))
QuestionLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

num_questions = len(QUESTIONS)
questions = random.sample(list(QUESTIONS.items()), k=num_questions)

num_correct = 0

for num, (question, alternatives) in enumerate(questions, start=1):
    QuestionLabel.config(text=question)
    correct_answer = alternatives[0]
    labeled_alternatives = dict(
        zip(ascii_lowercase, random.sample(alternatives, k=len(alternatives)))
    )

my_list=[labeled_alternatives]
print(my_list)
for k, v in labeled_alternatives.items():
    my_listbox.insert(END, k + ": " + v)
```

Result :

```
How_it_Works:
{'First US State?': ['Delaware', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Maryland'], 'Fastest car?': ['Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Tesla']}
<class 'dict'>
2
```

How database returns the data:

```
[('First US State?', 'Delaware', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Maryland'), ('Fastest car?', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Tesla')]
2
<class 'list'>
```

Data after conversion:

```
{('First US State?', 'Delaware', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Maryland'): ('Fastest car?', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Tesla')} <class 'dict'> 1
```

How app interprets it:

```
[{'a': 'Ferrari', 'b': 'BMW', 'c': 'Fastest car?', 'd': 'Mercedes', 'e': 'Tesla'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow what you're doing at the moment. I propose something like this:

```
questions = []
for r in records:
    questions.append({
        "question": r[0],
        "answer": r[1],
        "options": list(r[1:])
    })

for question in questions:
    correct_answer = question["answer"]
    print(question["question"])
    labelled = zip(ascii_lowercase, random.sample(question["options"], len(question["options"])))
    for label, option in labelled:
        print(label + ": " + option)
```

I've replaced the tkinter stuff with `print` so it was easier to work with but it shouldn't be too hard to change it back. It starts by creating a dictionary for each record which has the question, answer and options. I've then used a for loop to show all the questions, you'd probably want to show them one at a time with a button or something instead. The labelling of questions is similar to how you did it before but I've iterated the pairs instead of making a dictionary.

Comment: your comment definetly helps me in the right direction, but when I try to apply it back to my Tkinter app where instead of print() i am using a listbox, then suddenly all the options populate instead of just the ones relating to the question (I am guessing because we have all possible options stored in "option", so I need to iterate/limit it somehow). I will examine more, thank you!

Comment: For the app you'll want to keep a question counter or something and then only show a new question after the last one has been answered. In this example, the for loop will run everything at once, which is not what you want and was mainly to show the code worked.